# Google Contacts API Explorer?

Tags: javascript, google-data-api, google-shared-contacts

Ive been implementing a google contacts importer for our website and was looking for a way to test out the API calls so I can see the flow and what they return. There is a google api explorer but doesnt seem to have Google Contacts on there?

I know google contacts is still apart of the Google Data API but is there a specific explorer for that API set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API Explorer is specific to newer APIs, but you can use the [Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to try out any of Google's APIs. After authorizing you can click 'List possible operations' to get a list of API calls similar to what the Explorer provides. The main difference is there isn't a form to setup parameters, you have to go through the documentation and compose the request bodies manually.